# How to trigger re-login with HTTP POST request to j_security_check in Tomcat FORM based authentication

Tags: java, tomcat, web, websphere

We are now migration some very old apps from Websphere to tomcat ,but find a major difference on the behavior of FORM based  authentication

on Websphere

1. after login , when access login.jsp and raise HTTP POST request to j_security_check with username and password , user is login again

on Tomcat

1. after login , when access login.jsp and raise HTTP POST request to j_security_check with username and password , user is not login again , instead got a 404 on j_security_check page .

Is there any workaround on this , we need to keep the consistency on user experience

Comment: If you are migrating from WebSphere, maybe rather try [WebSphere Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/websphere-liberty/) or [Open Liberty](https://openliberty.io/about/)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with manually trigger request.logout and request.login while user request  j_security_check